# Show the results of database search with bean?

Tags: java, database, search, javabeans

I have a **Java Controller** and a **Bean** which is searching for something in a **MySQL Database**. That's the part which is working. But how can i manage the results of the search ? 
I want to show them on a new page (for the website i'm using .jsp).

> Input -> JavaBean (searches the DB) -> Page with the results

Answer (score 0):

A example

```
 <jsp:useBean id="bean" class="MyBean" scope="request">  
    <jsp:setProperty name="mypars" value="<%= request.getParameter("myprs")%>" />  
</jsp:useBean>  

<html>  
<body>  
....

</body></html>
```

see also
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahb.html